# How to call a function from click event inside another click event function?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 functions that triggers when an element is clicked. However, i want to use the first function that should be executed in another function via click event. I am still a newbie.

I already tried calling the function and declaring the function name inside the other function where i want it to be executed. Is it not working because the first function can only be triggered vie click event on its element? I also nested the click event on a function but it didn't work as well.

```
$(document).ready(function()
function toggleMenuClick(){

$('.menu-link').click(function (normal){
    normal.preventDefault();
    $('.menu-link').toggleClass('close');
    $('.overlay-menu').toggleClass('active');
    $('.menu-link').toggleClass('fixed');
    $('nav ul').toggleClass('show');
    $('nav ul li').toggleClass('fade-in');
    $('body').toggleClass('min-height');

    if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 99){
        $('.menu-link').toggleClass('white');
    }
});

}

toggleMenuClick();

$('.scroll-link').click(function(navigate){
   navigate.preventDefault();
      $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
      }, 700);
toggleMenuClick();
});
});
```

I want all the classes from `toggleMenuClick` to be toggled when `.scroll-link` is clicked as well.

Comment: Do not create event listeners in other event listeners.  This leads to duplicate event listener creations, and the chances of creating conflicts with the logic stepping on itself is very high.  Best case scenario you will be performing the same work multiple times.  Worst case scenario, it stops working.

Comment: Actually worst case scenario is it works some times and not others, and then it's a debugging nightmare to figure out why.

Comment: It was the last resort that I thought of but apparently was logically wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `toggleMenuClick` a separate function, outside your click handlers, so that you can call it independently.

It would look something like this:

```
var toggleMenuClick = function() {
    // Do classes stuff...
}


$('.menu-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleMenuClick();
});

$('.scroll-link').click(function(e){
    // Do stuff...

    // Now you can call your function
    toggleMenuClick();
});
```

Comment: thanks for this input. can i just name the function and call it instead of storing it in a variable?

Comment: Yup, you can do that like `function toggleMenuClick() {`. The only difference is if you do it that way, it's accessible before it's declared, via the magic of hoisting. Depends what you want.