# call a function inside a click function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a few images and a form where I have an input text, one pair of radio button and a select option, everytime I select one radio button and one option both of them get disabled and it can't be select anymore until the 'guardar cambios' button is clicked, when I select an option (in the sample it is the option 1) and an one image it changes for another but what I want is to, in case the person select the wrong option, to undo that, so I create a function where it has three parameters the value of radio and select and the class of the image selected, i call it inside 'seleccionar' where I reset the values of those three elements, then I put it inside the click function (the undo button). https://codepen.io/luzsdx/pen/ExKqwXP

I followed this [How to call a function from click event inside another click event function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55659793/how-to-call-a-function-from-click-event-inside-another-click-event-function)

But the problem is that when I choose an image it doesnt get replace for another, can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? thank you and I get the 'classes is not defined' error in the console

```
   function deshacer (classes, valorRadio, valorSelect) {
        $(valorRadio).prop("selectedIndex", 0).attr('disabled', false);
        $(valorSelect).val('none').attr('disabled', false)
        $(`div.${classes}>object`).attr('data', 'diente.svg')
    }


    $('.deshacer').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        deshacer(classes, valorRadio, valorSelect)
    })


    function seleccionar(valorSelect, valorRadio, classes, idImg) {
        if (valorSelect) {
            if (confirm('¿Seleccionar pieza Nro ' + classes + '?')) {
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        if (valorRadio == 'rojo') {
            if (valorSelect == 2) {
                alert('Extracción indicada es una prestación requerida.')
                $('#tratSelect').val('none')

            } else if (valorSelect == 1) {
                $(`div.${classes}>img`).attr('src', 'https://cdn-0.emojis.wiki/emoji-pics/lg/red-circle-lg.png')

            } 
        }
  deshacer(classes, valorRadio, valorSelect)

    }
```

Comment: Well baked! Now, for images you have not add any class or method to trace which image been selected so what you can do something like wrap a div for all images just after `<div class="body">` something like `<div class=body><div class="imagesRow"><!-- 1st Row -->....<!-- 2nd Row -->....</div></body` Then, you can add new css class called active once images selected where you'll be able to check for active images. Please see this example [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64341727/14435535)

Comment: thank you! but do I have to add an active element by default? and why the code doesn't take the parameter classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Global Variable**

Initial global variables so calling values inside a function can be done,  at top of your add those

```
var valorSelectValue;
var valorRadioValue;
var classesValue;
var idImgValue;
```

Now, mostly of time you can save, update selection of those variables sometimes they call it public/private variables depends in your needs and can be called it inside your function, in some other situations you might use `this.valorSelectValue;`

**Local Variable:** When you initial local variables that are defined within functions. They have local scope, meaning it should be used within the functions that define them.

**Global Variable:** They are variables that are defined outside of functions. These variables have global scope, so they can be used by any function and no need to passing them as parameters of the function.

Next, add new class named `defaultImage`

```
.defaultImage {
content:url("https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/teeth.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: auto; /*or your image's width*/
    height: auto; /*or your image's height*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Inside your function `seleccionar` I implemented new logic

```
function seleccionar(valorSelect, valorRadio, classes, idImg) {

...
...

} else if (valorSelect == 1) {

...

// Lookup for any active selection
if ($(`.active`)) {

// Remove added red-circle-lg.png from element
($(`.active`)).removeAttr("src")  

// Add defaultImage before removing active class
$(`.active`).addClass("defaultImage") 

// Remove active class
$(`.active`).removeClass("active") 
                
}
// Remove defaultImage class
$(`div.${classes}>img`).removeClass("defaultImage") 

// Add red-circle-lg.png Image
$(`div.${classes}>img`).attr('src', 'https://cdn-0.emojis.wiki/emoji-pics/lg/red-circle-lg.png')

// Add active class              
$(`div.${classes}>img`).addClass('active')
}
```

**Live Example: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/s1bp/pen/YzWydaa)**

Comment: If all went fine I will delete your code from codepeon.io, just let me know ! Happy coding =)

Comment: okey so I understand the change of image by adding classes and thank you for that but the undo doesn't work for the radio buttons and select can you explain me why?

Comment: Basically, your callback click function for button has `(e)` then it triggers `deshacer (classes, valorRadio, valorSelect)` but there's no data to be sent except for `e` the event triggered so when you do `console.log(classes)` shows output of `undefined` meaning it's empty. So, I would suggest holding the values in new variable top of file make it global and accessible as `var valorSelect = "";` and `var valorRadio ="";` and `var classes = "";` I hope that helps !

Comment: ok I understand and one more question, the class active where does it came from?

Comment: That CSS class could be your indicator, so if you would like to do borders, shadows, green tick or sometimes you might call the value inside a tag. Perhaps it's a way to trace selection made by user. If you had any more questions please let me know.

Comment: okay but if that class has no property and is not attached to an element, how is it related to the selected image? and also I add the three variables to the top to make them global but my code still doesn't work https://codepen.io/s1bp/pen/YzWydaa thank you for helping me, I'm still a newbie

Comment: I updated above answer can you take a look in syntax and definitions, and let me know where are you stopped at which callback and function.

Comment: The css class called active you mentioned is attached to `<img class="diente27 active" src="ex.png">` when it is selected and confirmed by user. Then, if user change his mind the class removed and attached to new selection. That's your indicator and you should start your next apps by building something can trace selections before doing your main functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223047/discussion-between-luz-and-i3z).